# Macro from Word does not work in Excel can it be modified for excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I realize that it is probably not supposed to work, but I have this visual basic code from a Word Macro that opens a piece of software linked to a piece of fluke equipment connectded to the computer and when the macro runs it inserts the image from the screen of the equipment into the word document, is there anyway to change this code so it does the same thing in excel?

```
 ' InsertInsertActiveScreen Module
' Function: Start FlukeView if required
'           Locate position for inserting Screen
'           Insert active screen at cursor position
Global Const AppName = "FlukeView ScopeMeter"

Global StartedFV90 As String

' Declare constant values

Private Const ER_NONE = 0
Private Const ER_DDE_CMD_UNK = 25
Private Const ER_DDE_NO_INIT = 26
Private Const ER_DDE_NO_CONN = 27
Private Const ER_DDE_NO_SERVER = 28

Public Sub MAIN()

    Dim chan As Long
    Dim Status As String
    Dim wordApp As Object
    Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    ' Display cursor as an hourglass
    Application.Cursor = xlWait

    If (wordApp.Tasks.Exists(AppName) = False) Then

        ' Start FlukeView as server (-s) Modification of these statement is required if
        ' FlukeView is installed in another directory as the QReport.dot template
        Call Shell(ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "FV90WIN.EXE -s", vbMinimizedNoFocus)

        ' Reminder for terminating FlukeView when closing the document
        StartedFV90 = "STARTED"

    Else

        If (Len(StartedFV90) = 0) Then
            ' Reminder to prevent terminating FlukeView when closing the document
            StartedFV90 = "NOT STARTED BY Fluke View Report"
        End If

    End If

    ' Setup a DDE link with FlukeView
    chan = DDEInitiate(App:="FV90WIN", Topic:="FlukeView")

    While (Val(DDERequest(Channel:=chan, Item:="DDEStatus")) <> ER_NONE)

        ' Wait until FlukeView is ready to receive commands

    Wend

    Call DDEExecute(Channel:=chan, String:="Connect")

    DoEvents

    ' Transfer the active screen and place it on the clipboard
    Call DDEExecute(Channel:=chan, String:="Screen")

    ' Read completion status
    Status$ = DDERequest(Channel:=chan, Item:="DDEStatus")

    If (Val(Status) = ER_NONE) Then

        ' locate bookmark for pasting contents
        Call Selection.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="InstrumentScreen")

        ' Paste the contents of the clipboard into the document
        Call Selection.PasteSpecial

        ' Convert to Inline Shape to prevent overlapping images
        For Each ScreenPicture In ActiveSheet.Shapes
            If ScreenPicture.Type = msoPicture Then
            ScreenPicture.ConvertToInlineShape
            End If
        Next ScreenPicture

    Else

        ' Error occurred
        Call DDEExecute(Channel:=chan, String:="Error" + Status$)

    End If

    ' Terminate DDE connection
    Call DDETerminate(Channel:=chan)

    ' Restore cursor
    Application.Cursor = xlDefault

End Sub
```

This is what i have no and i get a Run-time error '13': Type mismatch?

Comment: Seems reasonable - why doesn't it work in EXCEL? Is there just a reference missing? What error or compiler message occurs?

Comment: compile error: named argument not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know what works and what doesn't in your macro when transferred from Word to Excel. However, just looking at the code I can offer a few pointer to put you in the right direction:

1. Replace `Global` with `Private` for your global definitions. If you don't, Excel will give you a compile error: *"Constants, fixed-length strings, arrays, user-defined types and Declare statements not allowed as Public members of object modules."*
2. Replace:

   ```
   System.Cursor = wdCursorWait
   System.Cursor = wdCursorNormal
   ```

   with:

   ```
   Application.Cursor = xlWait
   Application.Cursor = xlDefault
   ```
3. Excel doesn't have an `ActiveDocument` but an `ActiveWorkbook` and an `ActiveSheet` for the active sheet in the active workbook.
4. I don't think you can find an easy way to call:

   ```
   Tasks.Exists()
   ```

   in Excel. However, you can cheat and call into Word to do this job for you:

   ```
   Dim wordApp As Object
   Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   ...
   wordApp.Tasks.Exists()
   ...
   Set wordApp = Nothing ' Call this when you're done with it.
   ```
5. The `DDEExecute` signature is slightly different for Excel, but I've never used it myself so I can't tell you if this will work. The second parameter is not called `Command` but `String` in Excel. Try replacing `Command:=` with `String:=` and see if that works.
6. `Selection.Copy` will copy the selected range, which is similar to Word. But you'll need `Selection.PasteSpecial` to paste it. Of course, in that case, you're copying and pasting over the same thing so you'll see no different. I suggest looking at the Copy/Paste functionality of the `Range` object in Excel.

Anyway, that's all I can think of right now. It won't cover everything that's different between Word and Excel, but it's a start. No one here would be able to help you fully, since you're relying on the functionality of a specific program ("FlukeView" or "FV90WIN.EXE") for a lot of the work.

Comment: I'm confused, what do i do with Dim wordApp and Set wordApp's as well as the Tasks.Exists(), the Tasks.Exists() is where i get my error now.

Comment: @CWIEC: I've edited that section in my question. Basically, you prepend `wordApp` to the various Word-only functions in order to access them from Excel. It won't solve all issues, but it can help with some things, it's a workaround.

Comment: So now i get a 438 error on the Call Shell(ActiveWorkbook.... Any thoughts? where exactly should Set wordApp = Nothing goes i out put after the second end if

Comment: @CWIEC: You would normally put the `Set wordApp = Nothing` at the end of the Sub. As for the 438, I'd assume it's at the `ActiveWorkbook.AttachedTemplate` part, since `ActiveWorkbook` doesn't have that property in Excel. Try just `ActiveWorkbook.Path`. You need to do some of your own investigation as well to fix all the problems, I can't (and don't have the time to) fix everything for you.

Comment: Sorry Thanks, I've only done simple things in VB like emptying cells or copying and pasting from another workbook. I apperciate your help!

Comment: If you have some free time ever my last issue is Run time error '13': type mismatch. That is on While (Val(DDERequest(Channel:=chan, Item:=DDEStatus")) <> ER_NONE) I know nothing about this kind of script so like i said if you get a chance or have some free time, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @CWIEC: Unfortunately, I don't work with DDE to know what works and what doesn't. As I don't have access to that program you're using, then I can't even run the code and test it. I suggest you have a look around the web for this particular issue or contact the program's vendor. Or maybe someone else reading this will have a clue.